"Essential values" of a function at a point?
Recall that the essential range $\operatorname{ess.im} f$ of a measurable function $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is a compact set. Denote by $f_k$ the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[-1/k,1/k]$, and $E_k$ the essential range of $f_k$, and let $E = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k$.
By Cantor's intersection theorem, $E$ is nonempty. This seems dangerously close to assigning function values to $f(0)$, which seems weird to me. Does this thing have a name and where can I find more about it? Or did I screw up somewhere?

To apply Cantor's theorem you need to assume that $E_k$ is compact (i.e. that $f$ is bounded) unless you want to allow for infinite values. Other than that, it does seem like we can assign to every $x$ its own closed set of potential values.

Thanks for that, yes I think I was thinking of essentially bounded functions.

The essential range of a bounded measurable function is the range of the Gelfand transform of the function. So it is natural to think of the essential range as a substitute for the range.

I'm not sure what the Gelfand transform of a function is, could you remind me?

It should be noted that $E$ may not be a singleton. For example, if $f = 1_{[0, 1]}$, then $E$ is ${0, 1}$.

@BillJohnson oh I think you meant, the spectrum of the operator that is pointwise multiplication by the function, yes I get it.

@DavidGao thanks for that, yes I am aware.

There is a way of interpreting what $E$ is. Indeed, any character on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ restricts to either the zero functional, or evaluation at some point $x \in \mathbb{R}$, on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. $E$ is exactly ${\phi(f)}$ where $\phi$ ranges over all characters on $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which restrict to evaluation at $x = 0$ on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. In a sense, this is the “essential” value of $f$ at $0$. I don’t think it has a name or any use though. (Also note that this depends crucially on the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, not just the measure space structure.)

@DavidGao that sounds about right. I'm trying to finish a paper and this is turning up.

@DavidGao, re, why does $x = 0$ get privileged in this description?

@LSpice I reckon it is not privileged, any other point admits the same analysis.

@NateRiver, re, that was my first thought, but, if ${\phi(f) : \phi\rvert_{C_0(\mathbb R)} = \delta_{x_0}}$ is independent of $x_0$, then you get the same set if you take all characters $\phi$, omitting the restriction condition, don't you?

That would not be independent of $x_0$ I think? In the case where $x_0$ is of interest, then OP’s $f_k$ should be the restriction to the intervals $[x_0 - 1/k, x_0 + 1/k]$.

@NateRiver, re, oh, right, sorry.

@LSpice Yeah, I only put $x = 0$ as the OP’s using intervals around $0$. This is equally valid for any point.

Geometric measure theory and its many elegant definitions give a way to make sense of these  notions. Indeed, many of its tools are well suited for this problem of assigning a pointwise meaning to functions.
Let’s work on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$. If the limit
$$L_x := \bigcap_{\delta > 0} \operatorname{ess. im}_{B_\delta (x)} f$$
is unique, then you can indeed assign a value canonically to $f(x).$
This is because $f$ is essentially continuous at $x$, a definition from geometric measure theory. $f$ is said to be essentially continuous at $x$ if there exists a null set $N \subset \Omega$ such that
$$\lim_{y \to x, \, y \in \Omega \setminus N} f(y)$$
exists. Such a limit is necessarily unique if it exists, and course it equals $L_x$ in our case.
One can also look at this from the Lebesgue point perspective. From this point of view, it is also not too surprising that you can canonically assign a value, since if $L_x$ is unique, $f$ is also in the sense of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, Lebesgue continuous at $x$, in the sense that
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{1}{\mu(B_\delta (x))} \int_{B_\delta (x)} |f(y) - L_x| \, dy = 0.$$
Such a limit $L_x$, which exists in fact a.e. for any (locally) $L^1$ function $f$ is known as the sharp representative of $f$ in geometric measure theory, and conditions for its existence at any particular point $x$ are weaker than that which you gave.

I'm not sure I know anything about "geometric measure theory" but I needed something stronger than "a.e." and the Lebesgue set for my application. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I have a closed convex set $Q(x) \subset \mathbb{R}^e$ with nonempty interior. I needed to generalize the notion $f(x) \in Q^{\circ}(x)$. If $f$ is continuous, the meaning is clear. If $f$ is piecewise continuous, I need that $\xi_k \to x \implies \lim f(\xi_k) \in Q^{\circ}(x)$, if the limit exists. The generalization of that notion appears to be $\operatorname{ess val} f(x) \in Q^{\circ}(x)$.

Hm, well i answered your original inquiry to the best of my ability. If you have a more specific question relating to your research goals, you could probably make a new post to ask. @SébastienLoisel
